# .htaccess rewrite from domain/ to domain/nl/

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, prestashop

I recently installed Prestashop which has URLs in the form of domain.nl/my-account . Now I added a second language which turns URLS into domain.nl/nl/my-account or domain.nl/en/my-account

As people have bookmarked different items and searchengines have indexed the site I would like to redirect visitors to the old URLS (without the language) to be redirected to the same URL with language (NL is preferred).

A redirect to the mainpage is all I could achieve up to this point. Does anyone have an idea how to set this up using .htaccess??

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: does this have anything to do with programming?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(nl|en)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /nl/$1 [L,R=301]
```

So you may need to change the `(nl|en)` part, because that regex checks to see if the URL already starts with `/nl/` **or `/en/`**. You can replace the "en" with whatever other language you don't want redirected.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I get a redirect loop error unfortunately